# Behat + Symfony, Custom definitions are not loaded

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink

I've installed Behat on my  Symfony2 project but my custom definitions are not loaded, did I miss something?

**behat.yml**

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://myproject.local/app_test.php/'
      goutte: ~
```

**features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php**

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
    Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
    Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareInterface;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Step;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{

    private $kernel;
    private $parameters;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     * Every scenario gets its own context object.
     *
     * @param array $parameters context parameters (set them up through behat.yml)
     */
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your context here
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    /**
     * Sets HttpKernel instance.
     * This method will be automatically called by Symfony2Extension ContextInitializer.
     *
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }

    /**
    * @Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)" password$/
    */
    public function iAmLoggedInAsWithPassword($username, $password)
    {
      return array(
          new Step\Given("I am on \"/login\""),
          new Step\When("I fill in \"Username\" with \"$username\""),
          new Step\When("I fill in \"Password\" with \"$password\""),
          new Step\When("I press \"Login\""),
      );
    }
}
```

**Scenarios:**

This one is ok:

```
  Scenario: Login success
    Given I am on "/login"
    ...
```

But this one tell me I should implement my definitions:

```
  Scenario: Logout
    Given I am logged in as "my@mail.com" with "password" password
```

error:

```
Vous pouvez implémenter les définitions d'étapes pour les étapes non définies avec ces modèles :

    /**
     * @Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)" password$/
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAsWithPassword($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

**composer.json:**

```
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "v2.5.1",
    "behat/mink": "v1.5.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "v1.1.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "v1.2.0",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "v1.1.1",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "v1.0.9"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony2 extension not only changes the paths but also the namespace of a FeatureContext (it looks for context files in a bundle).

If you want to keep your features outside of the bundles, you have to specify the main context class (context.class):

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
  context:
    class:  FeatureContext
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      default_session: symfony2
```

You might also need to configure the composer autoloader to load the context files from *features/bootstrap*. To do that update the autoload section of your *composer.json*:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": ["src/", "features/bootstrap/"]}
},
```

Comment: Thanks perfect! I didn't find it in the doc, do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I don't see the problem here.

Can you try to run `bin/behat -dl` and check if your step definition is printed?

Comment: I already did it but my custom definition isn't here.
I have `Given /^(?:|I )am on (?:|the )homepage$/` to `Then /^show last response$/`but no `Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)" password$/`